# How to set different colours with HEX values in Picker Background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, uicolor

I want to set three different colours to picker view background
one for the the background items one for the item which is currently in picker(selected item).How would i do that.

I have hex value of a color(#01445) so i have to set it for picker background. How to set these hex values.
And also i have to set this color(#014455) value to the selected item in picker.

```
myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]init];
myPickerView.dataSource = self;
myPickerView.delegate = self;
myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
myPickerView.tag=1;
[myPickerView setBackgroundColor:[self colorFromHexString:@"#014455"]];   //set different color here with hex value

UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                               target:self action:@selector(done:)];


UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:
                      CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-
                                 myPickerView.frame.size.height-(self.view.frame.size.width/6.4),self.view.frame.size.width,50)];
[toolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];

[toolBar setBackgroundColor:[self colorFromHexString:@"#ff7a03"]];    // i have hex value #ff7a03 so i have to set here

NSArray *toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         doneButton, nil];
[toolBar setItems:toolbarItems];
```

this is the function i have created for using her colours in background

```
-(UIColor *)colorFromHexString:(NSString *)hexString {
unsigned rgbValue = 0;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexString];
[scanner setScanLocation:1]; // bypass '#' character
[scanner scanHexInt:&rgbValue];
return [UIColor colorWithRed:((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/255.0 green:((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/255.0 blue:(rgbValue & 0xFF)/255.0 alpha:1.0];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need a category of `UIColor` with `fromHex` method and this is what I want to share with you

this is the .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIColor (Hex)

+(UIColor*)colorFromHex:(NSString*)hex;

@end
```

this is the .m

```
#import "UIColor+Hex.h"

@implementation UIColor (Hex)

+(UIColor*)colorFromHex:(NSString*)hex
{
    NSString * cString = [hex stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]].uppercaseString;

    if([cString hasPrefix:@"#"])
    {
        cString = [cString  substringFromIndex:1];
    }

    if([cString length] != 6)
    {
        return [UIColor grayColor];
    }

    NSString * rString = [cString substringToIndex:2];
    NSString * gString = [cString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 2)];
    NSString * bString = [cString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(4, 2)];

    unsigned int r,g,b = 0;

    [[[NSScanner alloc]initWithString:rString] scanHexInt:&r];
    [[[NSScanner alloc]initWithString:gString] scanHexInt:&g];
    [[[NSScanner alloc]initWithString:bString] scanHexInt:&b];

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:(CGFloat)r/255.0 green:(CGFloat)g/255.0 blue:(CGFloat)b/255.0 alpha:1];
}


@end
```

and then you only need is import this UIColor+Hex.h and modify your code using this method

like this

```
myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]init];
myPickerView.dataSource = self;
myPickerView.delegate = self;
myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
myPickerView.tag=1;
myPickerView.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorFromHex:@"#014455"];   //set different color here with hex value

UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                               target:self action:@selector(done:)];


UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:
                      CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-
                                 myPickerView.frame.size.height-(self.view.frame.size.width/6.4),self.view.frame.size.width,50)];
[toolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];

[toolBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorFromHex:@"#ff7a03"]];  // i have hex value #ff7a03 so i have to set here

NSArray *toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         doneButton, nil];
[toolBar setItems:toolbarItems];
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: actually i have already created function to set the hex color  please see the updated code but now my problem is i wanted to implement the background color for the row which we select from picker.

Comment: ok but my answer was 16hrs ago ;), you need to change to change your cell backgound color now?

Comment: can you please tell me how would i do that @Reinier Melian